# Highstock/Highchart OHCL not showing?

Tags: java, php, jquery, html, highcharts

Hey guys I am having trouble loading my data into the highstock charts.

I tired to display a chart with highstock

**my data.json**

```
[{
    "date":1395651841,
    "price":11,
    "amount":12,
    "tid":33170585,
    "price_currency":"USD",
    "item":"none",
    "trade_type":"bid"
    },
    {
    "date":1395651836,
    "price":4,
    "amount":3,
    "tid":33170584,
    "price_currency":"USD",
    "item":"none",
    "trade_type":"ask"}
]
```

And **my Html**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function() {
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {

        // Create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


            rangeSelector : {
                inputEnabled: $('#container').width() > 480,
                selected : 1
            },

            title : {
                text : 'Tiredddd'
            },

            series : [{
                name : '@_@',
                data : data,
                type : 'areaspline',
                threshold : null,
                tooltip : {
                    valueDecimals : 2
                },
                fillColor : {
                    linearGradient : {
                        x1: 0, 
                        y1: 0, 
                        x2: 0, 
                        y2: 1
                    },
                    stops : [[0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]], [1, 'rgba(0,0,0,0)']]
                }
            }]
        });
    });
});

        </script>
```

Please assist me in finding the bug

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have comma separated data.Please debug(alert(data)) like (1,2,3).

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {alert(data); // your other code......}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `open`/`high`/`low`/`close` properties in your data points.

See required format for Highcharts data [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#series.data).